# how to add to cart on website in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a code to add a shoe off adidas to my cart.
I am so far able to go to the website and have it check if the size is in stock. If the size is available, I want to program it so I am able to add it to cart. Any ideas?

What I have so far is:

```
import requests
import bs4
import random
import webbrowser

# Base URL =  http://www.adidas.com/us/BB9043.html?forceSelSize=BB9043_600
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

def URLGen(model, size):
    BaseSize = 600
    #Base Size is for Shoe Size 7.5
    ShoeSize = size - 7
    ShoeSize = ShoeSize * 20
    RawSize = ShoeSize + BaseSize
    ShoeSizeCode = int(RawSize)
    URL = 'http://www.adidas.com/us/' + str(model) + '.html?forceSelSize=' + str(model) + '_' + str(ShoeSizeCode)
    return URL
def CheckStock(url,model):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    RawHTML = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    Page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(RawHTML.text, "lxml")
    ListOfRawSizes = Page.select('.size-dropdown-block')
    Sizes = str(ListOfRawSizes[0].getText()).replace('\t', '')
    Sizes = Sizes.replace('\n\n', ' ')
    Sizes = Sizes.split()
    Sizes.remove('Select')
    Sizes.remove('size')
    for size in Sizes:
        print(str(model) + ' Size: ' + str(size) + ' Available')

def Main(model, size):
    url = URLGen(model, size)
    CheckStock(url, model)
```

Comment: What happens so far? How are you stuck?

Comment: As a side note you should try using [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to build the URL to be on the safe side in case the `model` or `size` contain some funny characters.

Comment: You should make `CheckStock` return boolean ( True if avaliable ) , and make an `AddToCart()` function that posts your data to the cart page.

Comment: So far on a terminal window, i open python: 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import helloworld
>>> helloworld.Main('BB9043', 7.5)
BB9043 Size: 7.5 Available
BB9043 Size: 8 Available
BB9043 Size: 8.5 Available
BB9043 Size: 9 Available
BB9043 Size: 9.5 Available
BB9043 Size: 10 Available
BB9043 Size: 11.5 Available